# How can I convert the value received from <input type="datetime-local"> to firestore format?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In a react webapp, I have a form with `<input type="datetime-local">`.

The value returned in chrome version 64 on Windows is in the following format:

```
2018-03-08T07:00
```

I assume that in other browsers it will be different.

I want to write this value in firestore, in the same format that is generated when I create, using the firestore admin GUI, a field of type 'timestamp', which is the following:

```
March 8, 2018 at 7:00:00 AM UTC+2
```

Any idea how to do this so that it works on all browsers?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local: _“Because of the limited browser support for datetime-local, and the variations in how the inputs work, it may currently still be best to use a framework or library to present these, or to use a custom input of your own.”_

Comment: Probably should use separate date and time fields... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Firestore stores timestamps in ISO8601 format.  If you use the console to add a timestamp and then `get` the document, the following is returned.

```
{"timestamp":"2018-03-16T15:45:36.000Z"}
```

I would recommend that you convert all times to a common format, so you don't have different time formats in your database.  A great tool for this, is [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).  I would recommend [ISO8601](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) format, as this is universally readable by most (if not all) browsers, apps, databases,etc.

Comment: Thanks, I know moment, but you didn't answer my question... maybe it doesn't have a good answer and I should use separate date and time inputs, as the comment on my question suggests.

Comment: I've updated my answer, which should make it clearer

Answer (score 1):

I set a default/initial value in state:

```
this.state={
    datetime: `${new Date().getFullYear()}-${`${new Date().getMonth()+1}`.padStart(2,0)}-${`${new Date().getDay() + 1}`.padStart(2,0)}T${`${new Date().getHours()}`.padStart(2,0)}:${`${new Date().getMinutes()}`.padStart(2, 0)}`
}
```

Then I create a controlled input that used the state value above...

```
 <input 
   type="datetime-local" 
   name="datetime" 
   value={this.state.datetime} 
   onChange={e => this.setState({datetime: e.target.value})}
  />
```

A little verbose, but it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I ended doing just new Date(value), where value is what I got from datetime-local. I did just Date(value) in the beginning, and it didn't work.

Comment: I thought your question was specific to datetime. Did my solution not work? If so what error are you getting, it worked for me. I suppose my solution is more specific to setting the default/initial value to the current time, which I was struggling to figure out, so I just reconstructed the shape of the timestamp manually.

Comment: Didn't try it, since taking the value that I received from datetime-local and using New Date() is sufficient for my needs. But thanks, anyway... (I marked the answer as useful :)

Comment: can you please accept the answer if it answers your question or answer your own question. The point is to help everyone by making this a useful point of reference, not just answer individual questions.

Comment: I don't think it should be the accepted answer, as there is probably no good answer for my question (see the first comment to my question). I think that just using new Date() is as good as your answer... :)  I marked your answer as useful - I think it is the proper thing to do :)

Answer (score 0):

To format the date, you should use this:

```
this.state={
    datetime: `${new Date().getFullYear()}-${`${new Date().getMonth()+1}`.padStart(2,0)}-${`${new Date().getDate()}`.padStart(2,0)}T${`${new Date().getHours()}`.padStart(2,0)}:${`${new Date().getMinutes()}`.padStart(2, 0)}`
}
```

Note: From  Josh's answer I changed getDay() to getDate(), because the first one returns the day of the week (0 -6), I don't have the sufficient reputation to comment it